# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named... Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

**dev** is my root directory. I have the below files.

```
dev\sitehealthcheck\test.py
dev\sitehealthcheck\draw.py
```

In **test.py**, the first line reads:

```
from sitehealthcheck.draw import *
```

If I run *test.py* in the VSCode terminal, everything works as expected.  However, when I try to execute **test.py** in the interactive window, Jupyter returns:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sitehealthcheck'**

What can I do so VSCode automatically searches for modules in the same directory as the file I'm executing?

I would prefer just to type the below line.. and, have the VSCode editor/Intellisense and Jupyter to automatically search for modules in the same directory as the file I'm executing.

```
from draw import *
```

Comment: If you add `.../dev/sitehealthcheck` to your `PYTHONPATH`, then you can `import draw`.

Comment: Thanks.  You answered my question.  I don't have a way to select your comment as the official answer to this stackoverflow question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the interactive window the current working directory is not set to the path of the file being executed, instead it's set to the path of the workspace folder that you have open in VSCode. If I have the following:

```
WorkspaceFolder:
    SubFolder:
      MyScript.py
      ImportMe.py
```

If you run `MyScript.py` in the terminal you would want this:

```
from importme import * since the file location is added to the path
```

But if you are using the interactive window you can either add to your `PythonPath` as suggested above. Or you can use this:

```
from SubFolder.importme import *
```

Since the CWD is set to the workspace root for the Interactive Window session.

Answer (score 13):

In support of the existing answers, you need to add the `jupyter.notebookFileRoot` line to your `settings.json` file in your workspace when using a notebook in a subfolder and modules in a sibling folder:

`.vscode/settings.json`:

```json
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python",
    "jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, you can search for a setting in the Python extension which is called "Python › Data Science: Notebook File Root". The line below the title of this setting says: "Set the root directory for loading files for the Python Interactive window.". Then you change ${workspaceFolder} to ${fileDirname}, close the interactive Python terminal and restart it, and it should work.

Comment: I don't know if VS code changed the default, but for me `${fileDirname}` was the default and I needed to set `${workspaceFolder}`

Answer (score 2):

Easy way to set proper kenral and venv. Try setting proper venv like below.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra URLs that can become invalid in future.

Comment: @Tyler2P the image highlights the solutions at up right-side corner which worked for me. Code can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

if error in jupyter notebook

1. open -: anaconda prompt

```py
pip install import-ipynb
```

2. open main file

```py
import import_ipynb
import first
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add `.../dev/sitehealthcheck` to your `PYTHONPATH`, then you can `import draw`.